# Utilizar TimeStamps para filtrar información de un DataFrame - Python

Tags: python

Tengo este DataFrame que representa datos aproximadamente 200 mil líneas de mediciones de **1 min en 1 min**

```
data                      rad     t_amb  pot       t_mod
2018-01-01 00:00:00 0.305   24.26746    3.0     22.396478
2018-01-01 00:01:00 0.300   23.57200    45.0    21.955995
2018-01-01 00:02:00 0.200   23.52663    28.4    22.239656
2018-01-01 00:03:00 -0.100  23.41020    30.5    21.658972
2018-01-01 00:04:00 -0.198  23.24851    23.1    21.378779
```

Necesito filtrar y crear 2 nuevos DataFrame en donde solo filtre las informaciones de **15 en 15 min**, y de **60 en 60 min**

Leí que lo ideal seria utilizar la función `TimeStamps`, por ejemplo algo así `timeStamps = [1, 15, 60]`

Pero no entiendo como funciona, me podrían ayudar por favor

**Intento que hice**

Voy a llamar a mi DataFrame de `df_dados` por ahora estoy aplicando este código:

```
df_dados['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dados['data'])
df = df_dados.resample('60min', on='data').mean()
df.head(40)
```

Si bien, el código me filtra las los valores en `60 min` pero me promedia los otras variables `rad,t_amb,pot,t_mod` lo cual necesito que mantengan sus valores de la fila

Comment: Y que has intentado, por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/486176/edit) tu pregunta añadiendo lo que has intentado

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Ahora edito la pregunta

Comment: Los snippets son solo para código html, css y JS

Comment: jjjj es bueno saberlo, soy novatoide

Comment: Lo que tienes **no** hace un filtrado en sí, lo que hace es una agrupación de datos por fecha

Comment: Tu dataframe tiene la fecha de forma continua?? es decir no hay saltos entre minutos/horas/dias??

Comment: Hola Carlos. En lugar de usar 'resample', debes utilizar 'asfreq', e indicar la frecuencia. Así, debes poner 'df_dados.asfreq('15min') y te devolverá el DataFrame filtrado.

Comment: Ahh con razon, si es todo continuo... es una serie temporal digamos

Comment: @JoséLuisNiñomalo epaa, voy a intentar a ver que onda, gracias

Comment: En cuanto tenga un rato hago una respuesta más elaborada y te la publico, que ahorita estoy cenando...

Comment: @JoséLuisNiñomalo genial, creo que hay un error. Y ahora entiendo lo que preguntaba Christian, mis datos de tiempo son continuos en 24 horas, pero después vuelven a repetirse las horas, me da un error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: Esto es porque la columna con los datos de fecha debe ser también el índice, si no, no funciona. Para hacer que tu columna de fechas sea el índice, has de usar antes esta instrucción: 'df_dados.set_index('tu_columna_fecha'). Yo lo he probado con varios Dataframes diferentes y funciona...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de hacer esto es usando la instrucción `.asfreq` con los modificadores de tiempo adecuados (en tu caso `'15min'`, y `'H'`). Puedes aprender más sobre esta función aquí: [función .asfreq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html#pandas.DataFrame.asfreq)
y sobre los modificadores de tiempo en este enlace:
[valores válidos de modificadores temporales](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

Yo he hecho varias pruebas con un dataframe como el de siguiente:

```
                     time     open     high  ...  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0     2021-01-04 00:00:00  1.22393  1.22414  ...          136       3            0
1     2021-01-04 00:05:00  1.22311  1.22319  ...           29      37            0
2     2021-01-04 00:10:00  1.22315  1.22315  ...           43      34            0
3     2021-01-04 00:15:00  1.22310  1.22356  ...           29      16            0
4     2021-01-04 00:20:00  1.22343  1.22344  ...           30      17            0
...                   ...      ...      ...  ...          ...     ...          ...
54388 2021-09-23 22:05:00  1.17473  1.17483  ...          114       0            0
54389 2021-09-23 22:10:00  1.17477  1.17478  ...          109       0            0
54390 2021-09-23 22:15:00  1.17468  1.17487  ...           94       0            0
54391 2021-09-23 22:20:00  1.17482  1.17489  ...           68       0            0
54392 2021-09-23 22:25:00  1.17475  1.17475  ...           77       0            0

[54393 rows x 8 columns]
```

Como se puede apreciar, el índice no es la columna `'time'`, así que aplicamos
`df = df.set_index('time')`, y obtenemos como salida un nuevo DataFrame:

```
                        open     high  ...  spread  real_volume
time                                   ...                     
2021-01-04 00:00:00  1.22393  1.22414  ...       3            0
2021-01-04 00:05:00  1.22311  1.22319  ...      37            0
2021-01-04 00:10:00  1.22315  1.22315  ...      34            0
2021-01-04 00:15:00  1.22310  1.22356  ...      16            0
2021-01-04 00:20:00  1.22343  1.22344  ...      17            0
...                      ...      ...  ...     ...          ...
2021-09-23 22:05:00  1.17473  1.17483  ...       0            0
2021-09-23 22:10:00  1.17477  1.17478  ...       0            0
2021-09-23 22:15:00  1.17468  1.17487  ...       0            0
2021-09-23 22:20:00  1.17482  1.17489  ...       0            0
2021-09-23 22:25:00  1.17475  1.17475  ...       0            0
```

A continuación ya puedes filtrar por el tiempo que necesites:
`df = df.asfreq('30min')` nos dará como resultado:

```
                        open     high  ...  spread  real_volume
time                                   ...                     
2021-01-04 00:00:00  1.22393  1.22414  ...     3.0          0.0
2021-01-04 00:30:00  1.22370  1.22399  ...     3.0          0.0
2021-01-04 01:00:00  1.22332  1.22412  ...     0.0          0.0
2021-01-04 01:30:00  1.22401  1.22440  ...     0.0          0.0
2021-01-04 02:00:00  1.22502  1.22502  ...     0.0          0.0
...                      ...      ...  ...     ...          ...
2021-09-23 20:00:00  1.17442  1.17458  ...     0.0          0.0
2021-09-23 20:30:00  1.17453  1.17463  ...     0.0          0.0
2021-09-23 21:00:00  1.17488  1.17488  ...     0.0          0.0
2021-09-23 21:30:00  1.17452  1.17461  ...     0.0          0.0
2021-09-23 22:00:00  1.17468  1.17476  ...     0.0          0.0
```

Atención, haciendo esto estamos modificando el DataFrame original, por lo que los datos se modifican para siempre, y si ahora quieres recuperar los datos de 15 minutos, habrás perdido información y obtendrás esto:

```
                        open     high  ...  spread  real_volume
time                                   ...                     
2021-01-04 00:00:00  1.22393  1.22414  ...     3.0          0.0
2021-01-04 00:15:00      NaN      NaN  ...     NaN          NaN
2021-01-04 00:30:00  1.22370  1.22399  ...     3.0          0.0
2021-01-04 00:45:00      NaN      NaN  ...     NaN          NaN
2021-01-04 01:00:00  1.22332  1.22412  ...     0.0          0.0
...                      ...      ...  ...     ...          ...
2021-09-23 21:00:00  1.17488  1.17488  ...     0.0          0.0
2021-09-23 21:15:00      NaN      NaN  ...     NaN          NaN
2021-09-23 21:30:00  1.17452  1.17461  ...     0.0          0.0
2021-09-23 21:45:00      NaN      NaN  ...     NaN          NaN
2021-09-23 22:00:00  1.17468  1.17476  ...     0.0          0.0
```

Espero que te sirva para seguir tu proyecto.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por la explicación. Quedó bien didáctico. Lo acabe de probar en mi DataFrame tal cual explicas, y aun me da el error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` 

Pero despues lo probé en otro DataFrame alternativo y funcionó. Por lo tanto creo que voy a tener que buscar y eliminar `index` repetidos en el otro, lo cual me parece extraño porque es una serie temporal, no entiendo como se puede haber duplicado un DataTime. En fin gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Ya resolví el tema del index com `df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]` ahora tengo otro problema que me salen todas las otras columnas `Nan` despues de aplicar el `asfreq` hahaha, así que creo que tendré que generar otra pregunta